# Adding background color and padding to row in Twitter bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, row, padding

I realise that padding in Twitter Bootstrap has been done somewhat to death and I have previously managed to achieve it to an extent but am currently stuck on trying to get my three `span4` columns to sit nicely on a padded white background row.

I have tried various ways of adding in an extra, unsemantic `div` but to no avail.

I have tried:

```
<div id="mydiv">

            <div class="wrap">

                <div class="row">

                    <div class="span4">
                        <ul>
                            <li>Random link</li>
                            <li>Random link</li>
                            <li>Random link</li>
                            <li>Random link</li>
                            <li>Random link</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div> <!-- .span4 -->

                    <div class="span4">
                        <ul>
                            <li>Random link</li>
                            <li>Random link</li>
                            <li>Random link</li>
                            <li>Random link</li>
                            <li>Random link</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div> <!-- .span4 -->

                    <div class="span4">
                        <ul>
                            <li>Random link</li>
                            <li>Random link</li>
                            <li>Random link</li>
                            <li>Random link</li>
                            <li>Random link</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div> <!-- .span4 -->

                </div> <!-- .row -->

            </div> <!-- wrap -->

        </div> <!-- mydiv -->
```

And also:

```
<div id="mydiv" class="row">

            <div class="wrap">

                    <div class="span4">
                        <ul>
                            <li>Random link</li>
                            <li>Random link</li>
                            <li>Random link</li>
                            <li>Random link</li>
                            <li>Random link</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div> <!-- .span4 -->

                    <div class="span4">
                        <ul>
                            <li>Random link</li>
                            <li>Random link</li>
                            <li>Random link</li>
                            <li>Random link</li>
                            <li>Random link</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div> <!-- .span4 -->

                    <div class="span4">
                        <ul>
                            <li>Random link</li>
                            <li>Random link</li>
                            <li>Random link</li>
                            <li>Random link</li>
                            <li>Random link</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div> <!-- .span4 -->

            </div> <!-- wrap -->

        </div> <!-- mydiv -->
```

The "wrap" div has the following CSS:

```
.wrap {
padding: 35px;
background-color: #F7F7F7;
border: 1px solid #DDD;
```

}

But each time, the row either gets pushed down to the next line or doesn't wrap around the content at all.

I have previously managed to add padding by using an unsemantic `div` after the row but this time, it doesn't seem to work.

Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks.

Comment: Your question sounds like you are mostly talking about styling--would you mind sharing any CSS you have tried?  For instance what is the class `wrap` doing...that's not a Bootstrap style.

Comment: Thanks Merv, have edited to add the CSS now, though it's basically a bit of padding and a background-color.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Rather than adding an additional `div` for styling, you should just add another style to the row, e.g., `row-padded`, and pass new styles down to the children of it accordingly.  For instance:

#### CSS

```
.row-padded {
  padding: 35px;
  background-color: #F7F7F7;
  border: 1px solid #DDD;
}

.row-padded .span4 {
  background-color: #bbb;
  width: 30%;
}
```

​

#### HTML

```html
<div id="mydiv" class="container">

  <div class="row row-padded">

    <div class="span4">
      <ul>
        <li>Random link</li>
        <li>Random link</li>
        <li>Random link</li>
        <li>Random link</li>
        <li>Random link</li>
      </ul>
    </div> <!-- .span4 -->

    <div class="span4">
      <ul>
        <li>Random link</li>
        <li>Random link</li>
        <li>Random link</li>
        <li>Random link</li>
        <li>Random link</li>
      </ul>
    </div> <!-- .span4 -->

    <div class="span4">
      <ul>
        <li>Random link</li>
        <li>Random link</li>
        <li>Random link</li>
        <li>Random link</li>
        <li>Random link</li>
      </ul>
    </div> <!-- .span4 -->


  </div> <!-- .row -->

</div> <!-- container -->​
```

#### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dXxLm/)

**Note:** You probably want to define a responsive explicit value (in px) for the `.span4 .row-padded` **width** rather than merely the percent width.  I only used the percent for brevity.

Comment: Thanks Merv, I can see that works in the fiddle but doesn't seem to work in my code, can I ask the relevance of the "container" class?

Comment: @onjegolders The `container` class adds styles to center all the content on a page (auto margins).  The code I wrote is in no way contingent on it, so I probably shouldn't have included it.  Sorry if that threw you off.

Comment: Hi thanks again Merv, have ticked your answer as I can't argue with the Fiddle. Though mine must have conflicting code somewhere or other. I've ended up going with three separate divs around the three span4s so the effect is a bit different.

Comment: How about I have span8 offset4 instead of just span 4?

Comment: @IvanWang, that should work fine also: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dXxLm/103/).  Just note that with the responsive css loading, the offsets get zeroed out whenever the viewport width drops below 768px.  If you are viewing the JSFiddle in editing mode, you may need to adjust the frame to be larger in order for the effect to be visible.

Comment: I didn't know how to select multiclass. this is awesome. thanks.